# Existing file editors in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there any existing php code that will allow me to edit and save files from the browser?

Ex: a text area on the page site.com/edit.php would save to a specified file? I want to be able to edit files on the fly.

I am hosting the site on XAMPP and cant seem to get FTP working so this would be a big use if I need to edit a file and cant get access to the hosting computer.

This is the closest I have found to what I need, however cant seem to get it to work (the goal is to change 'change.php'):

```
<?php
  if ($changefile) {
     $slash = stripslashes($_POST['filetest']);
     $filetochange = "change.php";
     $filetochangeOpen = fopen($filetochange,"w") or die ("Error editing.");
     fputs($filetochangeOpen,$slash);
     fclose($filetochangeOpen) or die ("Error Closing File!");
     }
?>
<form method=post action="">

<textarea rows="40" cols="60" name="filetest">
<?
// Implode CSS
$filetochange = "change.php";
print (implode("",file($filetochange)));
?>
</textarea><br />

<br />
<input type="submit" value="Change File" name="changefile">
</form>
```

Comment: Wondered why people continuously look for a ways to break their projects and put more security holes.

Comment: A typical mod_php setup doesn't gain scripts the permissions to modify existing files.

Comment: That's called a PHP shell or file manager. Google for it. Often used by crackers.

Comment: Zerk - This is just for file editing. XAMPP is restricted to only accept connections from my phone or my desktop, secure enough for what I need.

Comment: @WillKavanagh what error are you getting in your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`www-data` has to have write permission for the files or it won't work. Be careful with this. Either limit access to your own IPs (as you said) or put in a password protected folder with SSL.

```
<?php

$file = $_POST['file'];
$script = $_POST['script'];
      if($file&&$script) {
      $fp=fopen($file, "w");
      fwrite($fp,$script);
      fclose($fp);
   }
?>
<form method="post">
<?php
   if($file) {
?>
<textarea style="height: 90%; width: 100%;" name="script">
<?php
   $fp=fopen($file,"r");
   $t="";
   while(!feof($fp)) {
      $t.=fread($fp,1024);
   }
   fclose($fp);
   print $t;
?>
</textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="file" value="<?=$file;?>">
<?php
   }
   else
   {
?>
Name of file: <input type="text" name="file"><br />
<?php
    }
?>
<br />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```